# Cannot Git push on remote server via ssh

Tags: git, ssh, remote-server

Hi I'm new to Git and I'm having problems pushing commits on my remote server. This my setup

## Remote Server

I have a bare repository on /var/www/html/bare
git init --bare --shared

## In my PC

I setup:

git remote add origin ssh://username@hostname:22/var/www/html/bare

Whenever I make:

git push origin master

I got some permissions error and it can't push to my remote server

I tried:

chmod -R 755 . on my remote bare repo but doesn't work. i also look over the internet
and still got the problem.

Did I missed something?

Error

```
remote : error : insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database objectsW
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error : Invalid argument
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://user@hostname:22/var/www/html/bare'
```

Thanks!

Comment: please add the permission error you get

Comment: remote : error : insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database objectsW

fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error : Invalid argument
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://user@hostname:22/var/www/html/bare'

Answer (score 0):

ssh user@host "git init --bare /mnt/infy/bar/my-project.git"

Also please refer the link,

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Comment: I also looked on this but doesn't help. Thanks!